# Fix width of Text in Bootstrap

Tags: node.js, bootstrap-4

How can I fix the width of text so that it remains splitted in two columns

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6"><ol id="AllMessages"></ol></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1>Last Broadcasted Message:</h1>
          <h3
            id="output"
            class="float-left"
            style="
              margin-top: 35px;
              border-top: 1px solid #dedbdb;
              padding: 15px;
              width: 120px;
            "
          ></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few observations

- It looks like the text in the image  is put in without any space, this will usually break the layout - see the portion `width:width:width` etc.
- Your Markup is also incorrect as it contains `ol` elements without `li`
- Using inline `styles` on top of bootstrap is probably not a good idea as it breaks margins etc.

Most likely it's the text without non breaking text characters that is breaking your layout.

Comment: Thank You. Now I know what the problem is. And for ol tag it's dynamic so it will get the li enteries later.